# Parse PHPExcel file as HTML

Tags: php, phpexcel

I've got an upload page for users to upload excel files, this is part of a task request type thing. I am trying to have it so when the task is submitted, you can click a link that will then display an html table of the excel file they uploaded.  PHP-excel-reader would work perfectly, but it doesn't support xlsx files.  I'm looking at PHPExcel, but can't quite understand how I take those outputs and make an html table out of them.  I'm also worried I can't get ZipArchive supported in PHP.

Does anyone know of an example where they've converted the PHPExcel example to an html table?

**EDIT:**

The following code is working great.  It's creating a new file when the script is run.  I can't quite figure out how to rename the file correctly.  Currently it's renaming the actual phpexcel.php file containing the code below to phpexcel.htm.  I would like to take the name of the `$inputFileName` and rename that to `exceluploads/Book7.htm` for example.    I wasn't sure if it ws as simple as changing the `$objWriter->save(path/name.htm);` but that did not work, I received:

```
Warning: fopen(/exceluploads/Book7.htm) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/HTML.php on line 164

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not open file /exceluploads/Book7.htm for writing.'
```

Code:

```
    <?php

    /** Error reporting */
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    /** Include PHPExcel */
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';


    // Create new PHPExcel object
    echo date('H:i:s') , " Create new PHPExcel object" , PHP_EOL;
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    $inputFileName = 'exceluploads/Book7.xlsx';
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);

    echo date('H:i:s') , " Write to HTML format" , EOL;
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML');
    $objWriter->setSheetIndex(0);
    //$objWriter->setImagesRoot('http://www.example.com');
    $objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.htm', __FILE__));

    echo date('H:i:s') , " File written to " , str_replace('.php', '.htm', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME)) , EOL;


    // Echo memory peak usage
    echo date('H:i:s') , " Peak memory usage: " , (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) , " MB" , EOL;

    // Echo done
    echo date('H:i:s') , " Done writing file" , EOL;
    echo 'File has been created in ' , getcwd() , EOL;

    ?>
```

Comment: Have you looked at 17html.php in the Tests/Examples directory?

Comment: I see it, although I'm not sure why I'm so confused as to how to get PHPExcel to read certain files.  I'm looking everywhere and can't figure out where I can tell it to read a certain excel file.

Comment: /exceluploads/Book7.htm !== exceluploads/Book7.htm - this is  filesystem path, not a webserver path

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To read a file:

```
$inputFileName = 'example.xls';
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
```

To write a file:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML');
$objWriter->save('example.html');
```

Comment: I've edited my original post, didn't really seem necessary to post a new one, your example works great, I'm just having an issue naming the file.